# Writing a custom update method for a model in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, filter

I would like to write a custom update method for my model.
Basically I would like to make sure that the fields that being passed to this method are fields that are present in this model.
I came up with something like this

```
def update(self,dict):
    #Check if the fields in this data are present in this model
    for key in data:
        if not hasattr(self, key):
            #This property is not present
            data.pop(key)
    self.update(data)
```

However when I do something like this

```
modelMyobject.objects.filter(xxxxx).update(**dict)
```

This method never gets called. Any suggestions on what I could do to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running your model method in [Querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/), so instead of that, try either:

```
for i in modelMyobject.objects.filter(xxxxx):
     i.update(**dict)
```

Or writing [Custom Django Model Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers).

Comment: It seems like I need a Custom Django Model Manager. My model already has a  `objects  = GeoManager()` how do I create another one for my custom manager ?

Comment: You can override the GeoManager and put an update method there

Comment: I am marking this as the answer and Ill be posting a new question